# New self-signed TLS certificate on IIS 7.5 and Windows 7 not recognized

Tags: windows-7, firefox, certificate, tls, iis-7.5

TL;DR:  I have Win7 and IIS 7.5 with only one website on my PC, which is a dev copy of a site I am developing for a friend.  The site has an admin module that requires HTTPS.  Pre-Covid, everything was working.  After a 3-year gap in doing anything, Firefox and Chrome complained about the SSL protocol, so after some research, I enabled TLS 1.1 and 1.2 in the registry.  That *apparently* solved things for my friend and his local copy (also Win7 and IIS 7.5), but I am still having (different) server certificate issues on my PC.

After a bunch more research and playing around trying to get a SAN-enabled self-signed certificate that I could upload to IIS, and then realizing that the old IIS-generated self-signed certificate was expired anyway, I now have the following situation:

1. I have removed the expired, IIS-generated self-signed certificate from IIS and from the Trusted Root CAs list on my PC.
2. IIS currently has two self-signed certificates uploaded to it:

   - A new IIS-generated, self-signed certificate that expires in 2024 and is listed in my Trusted Root CAs list

     - Version: V3
     - Issuer and Subject: myHostname
     - Signature algorithm: sha1RSA
     - Public Key: 2048 bits
     - Key Usage [green]: Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (30)
     - Enhanced Key Usage [green]: Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
     - Intended purposes
       -- Ensures the identity of a remote computer
       -- All issuance policies
   - An MMC-generated, self-signed certificate that expires in 2024 and is listed in my Trusted Root CAs list

     - Version: V3
     - Issuer and Subject: myHostname
     - Signature algorithm: sha1RSA
     - Public Key: RSA (2048 bits)
     - Subject Alternative Name [green]:

       - DNS Name=localhost
       - IP Address=10.0.0.myLocalNode
       - IP Address=127.0.0.1
     - Enhanced Key Usage [green]: Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
     - Application Policies [green]

       - [1]Application Certificate Policy: Policy Identifier=Server Authentication
     - 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11.11: [looks like the friendly name in unicode]
     - 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.11.13: [looks like the description in unicode]
     - Key Usage [YELLOW]: Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment (30)
     - Intended purposes
       -- Ensures the identity of a remote computer
       -- All issuance policies
3. Firefox and Chrome both still see the old, expired certificate when I browse to https://10.0.0.myLocalNode/adminModule, https://127.0.0.1/adminModule, or https://localhost/adminModule.
4. The error message for Firefox 115.5.0 is SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN, which is the same error it was getting before I created the new certificates.  If I try to proceed anyway, I get "An error occurred during a connection to localhost. SSL received an unexpected Hello Request handshake message."  Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_HELLO_REQUEST.  This is also the same as I was getting before.
5. The error message for Chrome 109.0.5414.120 is NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID, I don't remember what error message I was getting before, but I think it was the same.  If I try to proceed anyway, I get "127.0.0.1 [or 10.0.0.myLocalNode, or localhost] sent an invalid response." ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.
6. I even tried using IE 11 (which I never use), and it gives me a certificate error page, too, although it doesn't show me the certificate:
   There is a problem with this website’s security certificate.
   The security certificate presented by this website was issued for a different website's address.
   The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.
   The security certificate presented by this website has expired or is not yet valid.

I've tried restarting IIS numerous times.
I've tried restarting my browsers.
I've tried F5, alt-F5, ctrl-F5, shift-F5 to try to get the browsers to refresh the page.
I've tried clearing my Chrome browser cache in its privacy settings.
I've tried restarting my computer at some point during the troubleshooting process, although at this point I don't remember exactly when.
I've tried running Windows Network Diagnostics when it is offered, and it doesn't find anything

Questions:

1. What am I missing?
2. What do I need to do to really get rid of the old, expired certificate?
3. Is there any way to get rid of the yellow warning on my MMC-generated certificate?  I tried unchecking making the key usages critical, but that didn't make any difference.  I think they are marked as critical on the MMC-generated certificate that is there now.
4. Could the problem be simply the expired certificate, and have nothing to do with SAN at all?
5. Is it a problem having two certificates?

Comment: *What am I missing?* The most important thing you're missing is Windows 7 End of Life date which was many years ago. It shouldn't be used online let alone to host websites.

Comment: A fair point.  As it happens, I got the issues raised here resolved, plus others.  After creating/trusting a new self-signed root CA certificate and using it to sign a new, nonself-signed server certificate with SANs using OpenSSL, exporting it with the private key to a .pfx file using encryption that is compatible with this ancient IIS version, importing it to IIS and binding it to the web site (thereby removing reference to the old, expired certificate), I'm still getting SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_HELLO_REQUEST error when I browse to the HTTPS pages.  This will only get worse with time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, commenter @ChanganAuto is right about "[t]he most important thing [I'm] missing."  While I've been focusing on the trees, the surrounding forest here is that Windows 7 and IIS 7.5 are beyond obsolete and really not compatible with modern browsers.

My friend is even more behind the times than I am.  He has a virtual copy of WinXP that he still uses for e-mail and is content to use an older version of IE to interact with the admin pages on his dev copy of the web site; whereas, I'm slowly moving towards Win10 - also old now - but have so far only transitioned for a few tasks that can no longer be performed on Win7.  Neither of us is particularly worried about security on our localhost copies of the web site (SSL/TLS works just fine on the hosted site), and we each have our own systems for lowering our risks for general online use of our old computers.

2. Expired certificate persistence resolved by going to the site in IIS Manager, clicking Bindings in upper right corner, highlighting https, and selecting one of the nonexpired certificates.
3. Yellow warning on the key usages for the MMC-generated certificate resolved by using OpenSSL 3.0 to create a self-signed Root CA certificate and a separate server certificate, importing the CA certificate into  MMC's certificate manager and into Firefox as a Trusted Root CA, and then signing the server certificate with the CA certificate.

Unfortunately, a new problem arose when I used OpenSSL to create a .pfx file from the server certificate and its private key and tried to import that into IIS.  I kept getting an error message that "The specified network password is not correct."  This was resolved by specifying a backwards-compatible encryption for the certificate and the private key when exporting them to a .pfx file.  The OpenSSL command that finally worked was
**openssl pkcs12 -export -certpbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -keypbe PBE-SHA1-3DES -nomac -inkey IISserver2.key -in IISserver2.crt -out IISserver2-legacy.pfx -name "IIS Server - Win7 Legacy"**
In particular, the -nomac option appears to be mandatory.

4. After all of that, the HTTPS pages are still not working, so SANs alone were not the problem, nor was the expired certificate, nor was enabling of TLS 1.1 and 1.2.  The current error message is SSL_ERROR_RX_UNEXPECTED_HELLO_REQUEST, and neither Firefox nor Chrome will divulge any more information.  I'm guessing that browser and server are not able to agree on a cipher and an algorithm, and at this point I think I've wasted all the time on this that I care to.

Someone posted somewhere that using OpenSSL 1.1 (I think it was) instead of 3.0 resolved his compatibility problems, which of course sounds like a ridiculous thing to do, but this is not for the public web site, only for an obsolete computer that is being used to test a localhost copy and only needs a simulation of security.  So it's within the realm of possibility that I will try that at some point, but not now.

5. Two certificates imported into IIS are not a problem.  Only one is bound to HTTPS on the web site.

Comment: Yes, we have (on several Stacks) about a dozen Qs about OpenSSL 3.0 up `pkcs12 -export` using modern PBES2 encryption and SHA256 PBMAC that older Windows -- and older Java -- can't handle. A simpler solution is `-legacy` (for 3DES keys and RC2-40 certs) or `-legacy -descert` (for 3DES on both, as you did more verbosely) (and in both cases SHA1 PBMAC).